# How to visualize trending over geographical area?

Tags: visualization, sql, geospatial, plotting

I would like to visualize how a percentage evolves in time over a geographical area.

In particular I have the percentage of products delivered in different regions and I want to show the weekly trend for each of the 21 regions. Currently I show a heatmap with the values of the current week and three line plots showing the trends of the 3 worst regions. I would like to show the full picture. Unluckily I can't use animations as I have to put the visualization on a static powerpoint.

I'm working with d3, sql and excel.
Any idea?

Comment: Given that the question is about visualisation, it could really help if you were to link a toy example of your current approach as an image (the text description is OK, but an image would be better). I or another user with enough rep could then make that an inline image in your question. Just be sure to use something it is OK to share - make up the data for instance, don't use your own project.

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks for the suggestion! My map looks like this: https://blogs.position2.com/imguploads/2012/02/heat-map-us.jpg but it refers to Italy instead of US and I have labels over each region with the percentage.

Comment: I meant an example of what you are currently doing. The heat map does not contain the line plots as you explain your approach, and everyone knows what a heat map is. The difficult thing is what you are asking about - how to show trends in the values associated with the map. Which is something you are doing - so should be relatively easy to produce a sharable image?

Comment: Have a look at cycle plots. Though these are not ideal for spatial data.

Answer (score 1):

Overly simple answer: "animate" this in PowerPoint by having one slide per time slice then advancing the slides quickly with the keyboard or set them to auto-advance.

If you have a little more flexibility outside PPT, there are free tools (e.g. Microsoft Power BI) where you could do a shaded map and have a time slider to make it more interactive.